# LinQ to XML query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using LinQ to XML to populate a dropdown list when my page loads. How can I cache the results so that I don't have to run the query each and every time the page loads? Also the xml file will only be updated once a day. Is it better to cache or just read it each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ToList()` on the results of the query. Then cache the results in a static variable, accessed in a thread-safe way:

```
private static List<Whatever> dropDownListValues;
private static object listLock = new object();

public static IList<Whatever> DropDownListValues
{
    get
    {
        lock(listLock)
        {
            if (dropDownListValues == null ||
                DetectValuesChanged()) // However you implement this!
            {
                dropDownListValues = // insert your query here
                                        .ToList();
            }
            return dropDownListValues;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard caching techniques. Please see [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/ImplementingCachinginASP.NET11302005072210AM/ImplementingCachinginASP.NET.aspx).

Comment: But use the concept from that post (caching is good), not his examples, which are really silly. (Why, in a webserver environment that shares a cache, do you have to dirty the cache via a file???)